# How do I build an hyper linked field of nested relationships in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have four models `User`, `UserProfile`, `Post` and `UserPost`. `User` is the default one which comes with Django.

`User` has a one to one relationship with `UserProfile`.

`UserPost` has a foreign key to both `Post` and `User`.

Now in serializer of `UserProfile`, I want to include all the posts by the user as hyperlinked fields. How do I go about this?

Following fails:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source="user.id")
    profile_picture = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000, allow_null=True)

    posts = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
         view_name='post-detail',
         read_only=True, many=True, source="user.userpost_set.post")
```

I get an error:

```
'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'post'
```

Obviously because `userpost_set` is a list of `UserPosts`. I don't want to build URLs manually with string interpolation etc, so how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a related_name on the UserPost models FK to Post:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="userposts")
    ...
```

And add a `get_posts` method on your `UserProfile` model:

```
def get_posts(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(userposts__user=self.user)
```

then in your serializer field, you can set `source="get_posts"`

You can also add an m2m to you `Post` model with `UserPost` as a through:

```
class Post:
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UserPost, related_name="posts")
    ...
```

In this case, you can access a users posts with `user.posts.all()`, so you in your serializer field, you can set `source="user.posts"`

Comment: Is there any other way than this? I don't make any changes to the model

Comment: You don't have to add a related name to your FK, try modifying the queryset in the `get_posts` method to `Post.objects.filter(userpost__user=self.user)`